# What is name of this oscillator and how does it work?

Tags: oscillator

I could not find any information on how it works. I created it on bread board and it outputs a pretty nice sine wave. Could you please tell me how it works or at least name of the circuit, for example, like the Hartley Oscillator?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It relies on a well decoupled supply so that C1 and C2 are in parallel with L1. Now can you see Q2 as a common base amplifier?

Comment: Colpitts oscillator. Or at least a variant of.

Comment: Normally it would have decoupling from the base to ground or you may not get enough gain to oscillate.

Comment: I will learn more about this Colpitts oscillator, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a common base Colpitts oscillator. Positive (oscillatory) feedback from collector to emitter (the emitter is used as an input). With C1 and C2 the same value, the frequency is dictated by the collector inductance and half of C1. It works more effectively with a decoupling capacitor across R3. If you take a look at my profile and some of the answers I’ve previously given, you’ll find much more detailed explanations of generally, how this type of oscillator works.